# Predicate for remove_if

Tags: c++

I have a vector I want to remove various things on depending on input from the user.  For example, if I have a vector with {1 10 12 2 3 10 5 6 29} in it and I am interested in remove everything that is greater than 10, how do I create a predicate to the remove_if function to do this.  And how do I make this predicate representative of user input.  The first time the code is run, everything greater than 10 might need to be removed, but the second time maybe everything greater than 8 needs to be removed and what needs to be removed is dependent on user input that is given once the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void remove_greater(std::vector<int> & v, int n)
{
    v.erase(
        std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [n](int x) { return x > n; }),
        v.end());
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 10, 12, 2, 3, 10, 5, 6, 29};
remove_greater(v, 10);
```